# How to debug a SOAP adapter in MobileFirst 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

In mobilefirst 7.0 I succesfully created a soapadapter starting from a wsdl URL.
The web server expose some operations, some work fine but one. I debugging on the webserver side an I see that a complex type is missing one object. Debugging with Mobile Browser Simulator I can see that the post request to mobilefirst server contains the json object I created by javascript. The json object contain an array of objects and a second object. The first object, the array, succesfully reach the webservice, but not the second one.
Is there a way to debug what the adapter does?

This is the prototype of the service:

```
        {
       "iscriviUtente": {
          "iscrizione": {
             "intestatari": {
                "item": {
                   "cciaa": "someValue",
                   "censito": "someValue",
                   "codiceFiscale": "someValue",
                   "formaGiuridica": "someValue",
                   "partitaIva": "someValue",
                   "ragioneSociale": "someValue",
                   "sede": "someValue"
                }
             },
             "utente": {
                "cap": "someValue",
                "codiceFiscale": "someValue",
                "cognome": "someValue",
                "dataNascita": "someValue",
                "dataScadenza": "someValue",
                "email": "someValue",
                "indirizzo": "someValue",
                "localita": "someValue",
                "luogoNascita": "someValue",
                "nome": "someValue"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

This is the javascript method I use to call the service:

```
            function doIscriviUtente(utente, intestatari, options) {
            var children = [];
            for(i=0; i<intestatari.length; i++) {
                var intestatario = intestatari[i];
                var child = {
                               "cciaa": intestatario.cciaa,
                               "censito": intestatario.censito,
                               "codiceFiscale": intestatario.codiceFiscale,
                               "formaGiuridica": intestatario.formaGiuridica,
                               "partitaIva": intestatario.partitaIva,
                               "ragioneSociale": intestatario.ragioneSociale,
                               "sede": intestatario.sede
                            };
                children[i] = child;
            }
            var param = [{
                   "iscriviUtente": {
                          "iscrizione": {
                             "intestatari": children,
                             "utente": {
                                    "cap": utente.cap,
                                    "codiceFiscale": utente.codiceFiscale,
                                    "cognome": utente.cognome,
                                    "dataNascita": utente.dataNascita,
                                    "dataScadenza": utente.dataScadenza,
                                    "email": utente.email,
                                    "indirizzo": utente.indirizzo,
                                    "localita": utente.localita,
                                    "luogoNascita": utente.luogoNascita,
                                    "nome": utente.nome
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }];
            var invocationData = {
                    adapter : soapAdapter,
                    procedure : soapProcedure+"iscriviUtente",
                    parameters : param
                };
            try {
                WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
            } catch(e) {
                if (options.onFailure)
                    options.onFailure(WL.App.getErrorMessage(e));
            }
        }
```

The webservice receive the parameter "iscrizione" which contains the array of "intestatari" and a a "utente" object that's null, as the soap adapter failed to compose the soap message.

Comment: You mean you've created the adapter using the service discovery tool? Is this a service we connect to as well? is there a project you can provide?

Comment: - Yes, Iused the service discovery tool.

Comment: And the rest of the questions?

Comment: -No, it'a web service I developed, and actually it's visible only on my own workstation. But I can provide the wsdl file, with axis it's very simple to create a webservice, then you can add some mock operation just to reply to queries.
- Do you mean mobilefirst project? Yes, I could. But I'm just learning mobilefirst and I do not know how to do. Using export as file-system from eclipse, it fails becouse of path-names too long.

Comment: @IdanAdar I found that I can export as MobileFirst Filtered Export, but it created a 28MB zip file.

Comment: Delete the native folder from the environment folders as well as the contents of the bin folder.

Comment: Do you mean delete from the zip file or from the project?

Comment: Before you export the project, stop the server (from the Servers view), delete the iphone\native folder (or android, etc) as well as the contents of the bin folder.

Comment: @Idan Ok, now it's about 1MB, what shoul I do?

Comment: Upload to Google Drive or Dropbox or whereever, and share it.

Comment: Any updates on the project?

Comment: @Idan I checked my boss, he disagree to share the progect over the internet. I would agree to send it to some IBM lab, as you are. He is about to buy Mobile first, so I could submit to IBM Service as a defect. I'm wondering to create a new project that use the failing functions only, but it's not so easy.

Comment: @Idan I you know another way, let me know.

Comment: Open a PMR (support ticket) when you can.

Comment: @Idan this is the link to a folder on dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2q29a1fmewm6xz9/AAAsJ-0es6UwQjaX88FGCl5Ca?dl=0 
Inside test folder you'll find readme.txt file with using instructions an descriptions, and projects zip files as well. I depured the project leaving only the minimum requirement to test. Enjoy it!

Comment: @IdanAdar did you succed testing my soap adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing an "item" in your javascript method. The code below should work properly.

var param = [{

```
   .......

    "intestatari":  { "item": children},
   .......
```

}];

Comment: Thank you. That made the job.